# Quaternion Differentiation Comparison and Oddity in Quaternion Composition/Multiplication scheme.

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, quaternions

I was trying to compare methods of Quaternion differentiation for propagating quaternion values over time for a body undergoing rotation, but am getting some strange results for some of the differentiation schemes.

The problem at hand is:
Starting with an initial quaternion orientation, a body undergoes constant angular velocity over a time period **deltat**.  I want to solve for the new orientation after undergoing the rotation during **deltat**.

I was able to find 2 competing alternatives that I was hoping to pit against each other:

1. Standard Euler Integration:
   [Quaternion Differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189185/quaternion-differentiation)
2. Euler Integration with quaternion
   composition:[How to use the quaternion derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896379/how-to-use-the-quaternion-derivative/2099673)

I am using the following quaternion for the test:

```
q=[-0.8628    0.1753    0.2406    0.4085]
```

under the following conditions:

```
deltat=0.5
w=1e-3*[0    0.7003   -0.6825   -0.5632] = [wr, wx, wy, wz]
```

I first calculate the standard euler integration as such:

```
omega=[0,-wx,-wy,-wz;
            wx 0 wz -wy;
            wy -wz 0 -wx;
            wz wy -wx 0];
standard_integrated=q+1/2*omega*q*deltat
```

I then calculate the equivalent rotation using:

```
qdot=exp(1/2*w*deltat)
composition_integrated=quatmultiply(q,qdot)
```

I then check for disparities between calculations using:

```
quatdisparity=standard_integrated*composition_integrated
```

where **quatdisparity** should be close to -1 or 1 if the end quaternions are similar.

---

The end results are:

```
standard_integrated=[-0.8628    0.1751    0.2407    0.4087]
composition_integrated=[-1.6872   -0.8556   -0.3888   -0.5196]
quatdisparity=.9999
```

The problem seems to entirely be in the quaternion composition.  **composition_integrated** is not a quaternion, and when one normalizes it to be a valid quaternion, quatdisparity drops to approximately **0.5**

Is the quaternion composition formula valid?  It clearly cannot produce valid quaternions if **1/2*w*deltat** has any positive components.  I would expect something like the standard formulation, where the new quaternion is very close to the original.  In the quaternion composition formulation, **qdot** is also not a quaternion, and is very close to a 4x1 array of ones.  Is this second formulation wrong?

Comment: The first variant is `(1+1/2*w*deltat)*q`, accordingly the second variant should be `exp(1/2*w*deltat)*q`, that is `qdot*q`, quaternions do not commute. In the disparity, you should take the conjugate in one factor.

Comment: Your matrix `omega` has some sign errors. Computing with `numpy-quaternion` gives very close results in both cases, with the matching digits being `[-0.862732, 0.1751131, 0.2406510, 0.4086935]`. Are you sure the exponential you used is a quaternion exponential?

Comment: Thank you Lutz.  I think the issue is that I didn't realize there was  a quaternion exponential.  I had applied element-wise exponentiation, which was causing invalid quaternions.  I will get back to you tommorow to see if this was the problem.

Comment: Yes, the quaternion exponential works close to the complex exponential, $e^q=e^{Re(q)}(\cos(\|Im(q)\|)+\frac{Im(q)}{\|Im(q)\|}\sin(\|Im(q)\|))$.

Comment: I have checked again, and it appears that the above recommendations have worked, and the values are indeed very close.  Thank you!